# Random Sorting Results in Lucene.Net 2.4

Tags: asp.net, sorting, lucene, lucene.net

How do I sort my results in a random order. my code looks something like this at the moment:

```
Dim searcher As IndexSearcher = New IndexSearcher(dir, True)
Dim collector As TopScoreDocCollector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(100, True)
searcher.Search(query, collector)
Dim hits() As ScoreDoc = collector.TopDocs.scoreDocs

For Each sDoc As ScoreDoc In hits
    'get doc and return
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an IEnumerable, you can use standard linq to randomize it. You can find an example [here](http://www.ookii.org/post/randomizing_a_list_with_linq.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Randomize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
   Random rnd = new Random();
   return source.OrderBy<T, int>((item) => rnd.Next());
}
```

If you want to do this inside of Lucene itself, you can [make your own sorter](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/05/17/a-z-0-9-custom-sorting-in-lucene/) (although note that you will no longer be randomizing the top 100 results, but rather randomizing all results).